# Boolean.parseBoolean("1") = false...?

Tags: java

sorry to be a pain... I have: `HashMap<String, String> o`

```
o.get('uses_votes'); // "1"
```

Yet...

```
Boolean.parseBoolean(o.get('uses_votes')); // "false"
```

I'm guessing that `....parseBoolean` doesn't accept the standard `0 = false` `1 = true`?

Am I doing something wrong or will I have to wrap my code in:

```
boolean uses_votes = false;
if(o.get('uses_votes').equals("1")) {
    uses_votes = true;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It accepts only a string value of `"true"` to represent boolean `true`. Best what you can do is

```
boolean uses_votes = "1".equals(o.get("uses_votes"));
```

Or if the `Map` actually represents an "entitiy", I think a [Javabean](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javabeans/info) is way much better. Or if it represents configuration settings, you may want to take a look into [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/).

Comment: ah thats a bit rubbish! ok, its good it wasn't just me. I'll use your suggestion. :) Thanks

Comment: Ideally `parseBoolean` would through an exception if it would get something other than `true` or `false`.

Comment: or it could be a little bit more lenient! But yeah, I agree - it was difficult to find the problem.

Comment: Or just use a [javabean](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javabeans/info) instead of a `Map`.

Comment: Interesting, although my datasource is an indefinitely increasing series of key/value pairs, so I guess, in this instance, it's in my best interest to use a HashMap.

Comment: Ah, this way. I'd extend map into a custom map with getters which returns different types. [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) comes to mind.

Comment: @Gabe on the contrary, `Boolean.parseBoolean(java.lang.String)` does not throw `Exception` if it gets something other than `true` or `false`. It just returns `false` everytime it gets something other than "true" or "TRUE" as string. [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean.parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @WarFox: Yes, that's why I said *ideally* it would throw an exception. If it threw an exception on input it didn't understand, there would never be any question of whether it parsed properly or just defaulted to `false`.

Comment: I just want to complement @WarFox comment by citing the documentation `The boolean returned represents the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".'` Specifically the "ignoring case" part; so "True", "TrUe" and so on are also true; in case anyone else was wondering it.

Answer (score 31):

I have a small utility function to convert all possible values into Boolean.

```
private boolean convertToBoolean(String value) {
    boolean returnValue = false;
    if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || 
        "true".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || "on".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
        returnValue = true;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why not just return "1".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(value) ||  "true".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || "on".equalsIgnoreCase(value);

Comment: Compare how Ansible does it: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#truthiness

Comment: Your on clause seems weird. If the possible values are on and off then this makes sense, but on isn't a definitive true/false situation like yes/no or 1/0 is. What if my possible values are on and under for example, then this logic wouldn't work. However, I usually try to set my booleans on DB side and simply use POJO to convert Database 1 and 0 into Java Boolean.

Answer (score 14):

According to [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) (emphasis mine):

> Parses the string argument as a boolean. The boolean returned
>   represents the value true if the string argument is not null and is
>   **equal, ignoring case, to the string "true"**.

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to get C's behavior (`0 == false` and everything else is `true`), you could do this:

```
boolean uses_votes = Integer.parseInt(o.get("uses_votes")) != 0;
```

Comment: Ah, thats an interesting work around, yes I guess that is the behaviour I was expecting. In this case I can guarantee that the output will either be 1 or 0 so BalusC's code works perfectly, however I shall remember this as it seems very useful.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but what about borrowing from C syntax:

```
(o.get('uses_votes')).equals("1") ? true : false;
```

Comment: The `? true : false` bit at the end is a well-known antipattern: it's just 14 extra characters typed for no particular reason, as the left-hand-side is already a boolean, and testing it to decide whether to return `true` or `false` is silly.

Comment: Thanks its help me

Answer (score 3):

Thomas,  I think your wrapper code, or just the condition itself, is the cleanest way to do what you want to do in java, which is convert "1" to the Boolean True value.  Actually, comparing to "0" and taking the inverse would match the C behavior of treating 0 as false and everything else as true.

```
Boolean intStringToBoolean(numericBooleanValueString) {
  return !"0".equals(numericBooleanValueString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a note ,
for those who need to have null value for things other than "true" or "false" strings ,  you can use the function below

```
public Boolean tryParseBoolean(String inputBoolean)
{    
    if(!inputBoolean.equals("true")&&!inputBoolean.equals("false")) return null;
    return Boolean.valueOf(inputBoolean);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns true if comes 'y', '1', 'true', 'on'or whatever you add in similar way

```
boolean getValue(String value) {
  return ("Y".equals(value.toUpperCase()) 
      || "1".equals(value.toUpperCase())
      || "TRUE".equals(value.toUpperCase())
      || "ON".equals(value.toUpperCase()) 
     );
}
```

Comment: oh, no, why not just use the new stringified `switch(value.toUpperCase())`, or even better, a `HashSet`? How many times do you plan to execute `toUppercase`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and i solved it with that:

```
Boolean use_vote = o.get('uses_votes').equals("1") ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is strongly typed. 0 and 1 are numbers, which is a different type than a boolean. A number will never be equal to a boolean.

Comment: technically, in my implementation, they're strings! :p Anyway, coming from a php/javascript background I guess I just assumed that it could distinguish between 0 and 1, on and off, yes and no and true and false appropriately.

Comment: Well, first.. what a variable currently is doesn't matter in this context since the whole goal is to *convert* to a boolean, from something else. Second, you're assuming they're numbers. If the origin is a query string, for example, it'll actually come in as a string just as much as "true" and "false" would.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
boolean uses_votes =
  ( "|1|yes|on|true|"
      .indexOf("|"+o.get("uses_votes").toLowerCase()+"|")
      > -1
  );
```